# Was the change in the hockey mask an intentional "New Beginning"?

Tags: costume, friday-the-13th, friday-the-13th-a-new-beginning

**SPOILER ALERT**

In [*Friday the 13th: A New Beginning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th:_A_New_Beginning), Jason Voorhees is not actually the killer, but a copycat named Roy Burns is the killer and goes on a rampage to avenge his son's death.

Roy wears a hockey mask, but one with 2 blue triangles:

[image]

The franchise received so much backlash from fans, that they brought Jason back in the next film wearing his signature hockey mask with the 3 red triangles.

> Paramount noted the fan outrage and took great pains to reverse the
>   damage with the inevitable sequel, which was tellingly titled Friday
>   The 13th Part VI: Jason Lives. Was it any cop? We’ll find out soon,
>   won’t we?

Jason Voorhees original hockey mask in Part III:

[image]

**NOTE:** I understand that this is a completely different killer and not Jason Voorhees and that would be the explanation for the different masks.

My question is: **Is there any evidence from filmmakers that they changed the mask to give fans some sort of hint that this really wasn't Jason Voorhees?  Is there any evidence that filmmakers were planning on changing the mask for each killer if it weren't for the backlash of fans?**